# How to make OpenGL ES 2 run multi-threaded using GCD / NSOperationQueue on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, grand-central-dispatch

Apple's docs say I'm doing everything right, but I get a hard crash with Apple's driver crashing internally 100% reproducibly on a simple OpenGL ES 2 program.

It appears there is a major bug in Apple's driver w.r.t. multithreaded access *while following Apple's instructions on multithreaded access*. Or ... I'm missing something in the docs, even though I've read, re-read them multiple times :(.

I would be extremely happy to use either NSOperations *or* GCD (they're implemented the same under the hood anyway), but I cannot get either to work.

Here's what I know / have tried:

1. All on main thread = works fine:

   1. Setup GL, render a single triangle, load textures, load geometry, render full scene
2. GCD = hard crash as soon as the background GCD "finishes"

   1. Setup GL on main thread, render a single triangle
   2. dispatch_async() to create new EAGLContext, load textures, geometry
   3. Render on main thread
3. NSOperationQueue = hard crash as soon as the background GCD "finishes"

   1. Setup GL on main thread,render a single triangle, create new NSOperationQueue
   2. addOperationWithBlock: to create new EAGLContext, load textures, geometry
   3. Render on main thread

Additional notes / things Apple instructs us to do:

- CHECKED: I'm connecting the new EAGLContext to the old by sharing the ShareGroup property
- CHECKED: I tried explicitly glFlush() immediately after loading textures + geometry (no effect either way)
- CHECKED: I tried re-using the original thread's EAGLContext (bad idea!) - different crash, not surprising since Apple says this is undefined and will crash

Comment: If you have a reproducible bug then log it with Apple at: http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: The last OpenGL bug I logged with Apple was accepted - and then I got a rant from an Apple engineer who agreed it was broken but didn't want to fix it. Doesn't help me :(. Also: makes me very disinterested in filing more bugs (and getting more abuse)

Comment: Sorry to hear that; sounds most unprofessional of them. But please log it anyway, eventually a more competent engineer will come along (may already have done so) and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain what you are trying to do, but consider the two following things:

1. An OpenGL ES 2 context cannot be live on more than one thread at the same time.

   However, you can use a single context in several threads if you always remember to switch each thread between null context and your context so you won't have your context set in two threads *at the same time*.
2. This part I am less certain about. You can have shared contexts, but the shared context should be used only for loading textures for the first context, it's not suppose to be used for rendering as well.

   Not sure how it's enforced in practice and what happens if you do render with a shared context.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you, at least, you can load Textures on a Serial Queue with sharegroup-ed GLContext. In my code, and in cocos2d for iPhone code, No problems at all.

You should check the cocos2d code for that.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc/blob/v3.4/cocos2d/CCTextureCache.m